# how to make the table scrollable with fixed header and the table content from mysql

Tags: php, html, css

How can I make this table scrollable? I've tried different code but I always encounter a problem on this line: `$avaya=mysql_query("SELECT * From avaya_pabx");`. Other code that I've used had a problem when I echoed the `<td>`.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="pageContent">

<title>Avaya PABX</title>
<table class='hovertable'>
<tr>
<th width="31">---</th>
<th width="12%">Critical Spare ID</th>
<th width="11%">Serial No.</th>
<th width="8%">Comcode</th>
<th width="9%">Version</th>
<th width="12%">Circuit Pack</th>
<th width="13%">Classification</th>
<th width="8%">Location</th>
<th width="12%">Availability</th>
<th width="5%">Date</th>
<th width="7%">Client</th>
</tr>

<?php

$avaya=mysql_query("SELECT * From avaya_pabx");

$alternate=0;

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($avaya))
{
$alternate++;
if ($alternate==3)
$alternate=1;
echo "<tr class=class$alternate onmouseover=\"this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';\"          onmouseout=\"this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';\">";
echo "<td><font size=1><a href='deleteavaya.php?serial_no=" . $row['serial_no'] . "' onclick=\"return confirmdelete('$row[serial_no]')\">[Delete]</a></font></td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['critical_spare_id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['serial_no'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['comcode'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['version'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['circuit_pack'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['classification'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['location'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['availability'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['client'] . "</td>";
}

?>
</table>

<style>
#pageContent 
{
    width:100%;
    height:18cm;
    overflow:scroll;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

echo the table contents into new table inside of a div that has the following css applied to is:

```
width:auto; /* or what you need it to be */
height: 500px; /* make this the size you want the data to be displayed in */
overflow: auto; /* this adds the scroll bars to the div when any data exceeds its hieght */
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to add

```
table tbody{
  display: block;
  height: 150px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

> in `height` add the default one that you need